# JsonObject unexpected token at a certain position

Tags: json, arduino, iot

Hope you're doing well. Im developing a proyect where I need to upload many variables to Google Spreadsheets, for what I'm using IFTTT, which only let me upload 3 values apart from the event name and the upload date.

So, I figured out that to upload more values to my Google Sheet, I'd only need two out of the three values, because I will upload all the variables separated by commas in the slot reserved for "value 1", and a Google Sheet/Excel command to separate it in many cells after uploading them in "value 2".

I tried an example of this in the WebHooks documentation page in IFTTT, and it worked, the problem comes when I create the jsonObject in Arduino IDE, since the code complies and get uploaded to my ESP8266, but in the serial monitor, show me the following error.

> 14:19:37.419 -> Connecting to maker.ifttt.com 14:19:37.606 -> Request
> resource: /trigger/my_file_name/with/key/my_key 14:19:37.606 ->
> {"value1":"0,0,0,0,0,0","value2":"=SPLIT(INDICE(1:2000;
> FILA();(COLUMNA()-1));",")"} 14:19:38.290 -> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
> 14:19:38.290 -> Date: Sun, 26 Sep 2021 18:19:36 GMT 14:19:38.290 ->
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 14:19:38.290 ->
> Content-Length: 68 14:19:38.290 -> Connection: close 14:19:38.290 ->
> X-Powered-By: Express 14:19:38.290 -> ETag:
> W/"44-aUxYR3gnF4RvNYXG8uY3kJzvmM0" 14:19:38.290 -> 14:19:38.290 ->
> {"errors":[{"message":"Unexpected token } in JSON at position
> 83"}]}Reboot: 14:19:47.425 ->

Seems line a syntax issue, I tried changing (and deleting) characters like "{", "}", but the issues continue, what could be causing this?

The code to create the jsonOject is this:

```
   int test_value = 1;
   int t1 = test_value*1;
   int t2 = test_value*2;
   int t3 = test_value*3;
   int t4 = test_value*4;
   int t5 = test_value*5;
   int t6 = test_value*6;

   String sgs = "=SPLIT(INDICE(1:2000; FILA();(COLUMNA()-1));\",\")";
   
   String jsonObject = String("{\"value1\":\"") + t1 + "," + t2 + "," + t3 + "," + t4 + "," + t5 + "," + t6 + "\",\"value2\":\"" + sgs + "\"}";
   Serial.println(jsonObject);
```

I'll thank any advice or recommendation you could grant me!

Comment: Have you validated that your JSON is correct? There are online JSON validators such as https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json should be written as

```
{"value1":"0,0,0,0,0,0","value2":"=SPLIT(INDICE(1:2000; FILA();(COLUMNA()-1));\",\")"}
```

with additional backslashes. But be careful, sometimes the backslashes disappear by intermediate transformation and must be doubled to avoid this.

So, replace by

```
String sgs = "=SPLIT(INDICE(1:2000; FILA();(COLUMNA()-1));\\\",\\\")";
```

Comment: Sorry, and how can I define it with variables? Because the values you told me are after the variables being set, I get the issue at this line:

String jsonObject = String("{\"value1\":\"") + t1 + "," + t2 + "," + t3 + "," + t4 + "," + t5 + "," + t6 + "\",\"value2\":\"" + sgs + "\"}";

Comment: I have completed my answer!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Couldn't test your fix till now, it worked neat! Thanks a lot for it!